Disabling console log messages from Edge webdriver in selenium-wire
I've been making a cli application that involves opening the Edge browser and getting some request headers, and for that I've been using the selenium-wire library. The problem is that, since it's a cli app, the log messages that it shows in the console become really disruptive and annoying.
These are messages such as:
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:64147/devtools/browser/afadf548-d020-4935-b37c-066b1be54c66
or errors such as:
[13784:34012:1228/034809.437:ERROR:fallback_task_provider.cc(127)] Every renderer should have at least one task provided by a primary task provider. If a "Renderer" fallback task is shown, it is a bug. If you have repro steps, please file a new bug and tag it as a dependency of crbug.com/739782.
which, despite being errors, don't actually seem to affect how the webdriver behaves at all.
This is the code I'm using to create the webdriver.
from seleniumwire import webdriver

options = webdriver.EdgeOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless")


driver = webdriver.Edge(options=options)

I've already tried adding options.add_argument("--log-level=3"), options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging']), options.add_argument('--disable-gpu'), I tried using a Service from selenium like so:
from selenium.webdriver.edge.service import Service

...

service = Service(log_output="nul", service_args=["--log-level=OFF"])

...

driver = webdriver.Edge(options=options, service=service)

as specified in the selenium docs, but none of it works.
